# Why does bundle ignore "gem 'pg'"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, pg

**Currently Working**

Not sure what happened.
Built gemfile.lock on a linux box and moved it over. Had missing things, ran bundle install, worked.

---

Bundle is ignoring my inclusion of the "pg" gem in my Gemfile. Installing pg through `gem install pg` works fine, and it shows up when I use `gem list --local`.

Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails' 
gem 'pg'
```

`bundle install` (no pg):

```
Using rake (10.0.4)
Using i18n (0.6.1)
Using multi_json (1.7.2)
Using activesupport (3.2.13)
Using builder (3.0.4)
Using activemodel (3.2.13)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using journey (1.0.4)
Using rack (1.4.5)
Using rack-cache (1.2)
Using rack-test (0.6.2)
Using hike (1.2.2)
Using tilt (1.3.7)
Using sprockets (2.2.2)
Using actionpack (3.2.13)
Using mime-types (1.23)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using treetop (1.4.12)
Using mail (2.5.3)
Using actionmailer (3.2.13)
Using arel (3.0.2)
Using tzinfo (0.3.37)
Using activerecord (3.2.13)
Using activeresource (3.2.13)
Using json (1.7.7)
Using rack-ssl (1.3.3)
Using bundler (1.3.5)
Using rdoc (3.12.2)
Using thor (0.18.1)
Using railties (3.2.13)
Using rails (3.2.13)
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

`bundle show pg`:

```
Could not find gem 'pg'.
Did you mean pg?
```

`gem list --local` (pg exists):

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.13)
actionpack (3.2.13)
activemodel (3.2.13, 3.1.11)
activerecord (3.2.13)    
activeresource (3.2.13)
activesupport (3.2.13, 3.1.11)
arel (3.0.2)
bigdecimal (1.2.0)
builder (3.0.4)
bundler (1.3.5)
erubis (2.7.0)
hike (1.2.2)
i18n (0.6.4, 0.6.1)
io-console (0.4.2)
journey (1.0.4)
json (1.7.7)
mail (2.5.3)
mime-types (1.23)
minitest (4.3.2)
multi_json (1.7.2)
pg (0.15.1 x64-mingw32)
polyglot (0.3.3)
psych (2.0.0)
rack (1.4.5, 1.3.10)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-mount (0.8.3)
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.13)
railties (3.2.13)
rake (10.0.4, 0.9.6)
rdoc (4.0.0, 3.12.2)
rubygems-update (2.0.3)
sprockets (2.2.2, 2.0.4)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
thor (0.18.1)
tilt (1.3.7)
treetop (1.4.12)
tzinfo (0.3.37)
```

Also, if I try to run `rails s`, `rake db:create`, etc., I get:

```
rake aborted!
Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adap
ter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)

Tasks: TOP => db:create
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Using:

```
Windows 7, 64-bit
Rails 3.2.13
ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24) [x64-mingw32]
Bundler version 1.3.5
```

Comment: You could try running `bundle update`.

Comment: Same results. Thank you though.

Comment: Could you post your Gemfile.lock ? Also, are you trying to use windows generated lock file on linux machine ?

Comment: Not sure why this has been closed. I'm experiencing the same situation at the moment, with the bundler refusing to add the PG gem to my bundle. I don't think this is a narrow situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try deleting your "gemfile.lock" and then re-running `bundle install`?

Comment: Thank you, I have tried this several times before and just tried again to make sure. Does not solve the problem.

Comment: didn't work for me on Mac OS X Yoshemite

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `Gemfile.lock` and run `bundle check` to see if the dependencies listed in Gemfile are satisfied by currently installed gems.